# Permalink Problems

Tags: custom-taxonomy, 404-error, url-rewriting

I am having a problem. I am running WP 3.05 with one custom taxonomy.

Here is the code to create the taxonomy:

```
function create_property_taxonomies() 
{
  // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Property Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Property Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Property Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Property Types' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Property Type' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Property Type:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Property Typee' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Property Type' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Property Type' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Property Type' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Property Type' ),
  );    

  register_taxonomy('property_type',array('sbproperty'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
  ));
global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['property_type'] = array('%property_type%', EP_NONE);
}
```

I have used the extra permastruct so the taxonomy just appears on the base url like site.com/taxonomy-slug instead of site.com/taxonomy/taxonomy-slug

I am also using the top-level-cats plugin to do the same for original taxonomies.

But this is causing a conflict with my pages. When I remove the permastruct the page loads on the pretty permalink, but with my permastruct on it does not, it gives a 404 for all top level pages.

Comment: You might wanna check `$permalink_structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );` in case you're migrating from one host to another ... I know it's not the solution, but it might help you in other cases.

Comment: To clarify things: `site.com/houses/` can be a page, a `property_type` or a category? What is your current permalink structure? (Use `@Jan` in your reply and I get a notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, this is becoming a habit, but I found a solution, as follows:

set rewrite to false in taxonomy registration:
   register_taxonomy('property_type',array('sbproperty'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => false
  ));

And create my own rule

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('init','flushRules');


function flushRules(){
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}


function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
$newrules = array();
$newrules["([a-z]+)-in-turkey-for-sale/?$"] 'index.php?property_type=$matches[1]-in-turkey-for-sale';
return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Comment: Horrible idea, flushing rewrite rules on init. Just visit the permalinks page to flush rewrite rules. Flushing the rewrite rules is a very memory-heavy process; besides, it only needs to be done once.

Comment: Which is why I comment out that part after I add any new rules.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things to solve this issue and nothing helped, except this:

```
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

but then categories stopped working, so I removed this code.

And then an idea came up :)

I left the code intact as it was and just re-saved my Custom Structure in Permalink Settings via admin, and now everything works perfectly.

**So solution is to re-save Settings > Permalinks**.